The storage of the C drive does not decrease even after deleting files
I’m an engineering student who uses Ubuntu for simulations, so I don’t have a detailed background in Linux systems.
Recently, I ran a Lua-based simulation in the home directory and generated large text files. I then copied and pasted these files to the D drive, and deleted the files that were originally in the home directory.
I expected that the disk space on the C drive, where Ubuntu is installed, would decrease. However, this was not the case. In fact, I found that the Ubuntu app still occupies a significant amount of space even after the files were deleted.
Using the du command to analyze the disk usage, I found that the space usage significantly increased in the /mnt directory after the simulation
What I tried

The trash has been emptied(rm -rf ~/.local/share/Trash/files/*), but there is no effect.

I tried using lsof, but it also had no effect (nothing appeared in the list).


Question

How do i free up space on the C drive?
Is my method of deleting files not appropriate?


Ubuntu doesn't have C or D drives/partitions; I gather you're asking about wsl which complicates things (deleting files on Ubuntu will cause the space to be freed up, unless your chosen file-system has a trash or equivalent procedure & you used GUI tools; CLI usually skips trash procedures; you gave no clear clues as to file-systems involved)

@guiverc I found that the ext4 has become very large
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.Ubuntu_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState

That is a windows path, and related to a windows configuration issue; your last comment does not refer to a Ubuntu file, or Ubuntu file-system (there is no C:\Users in Ubuntu file-systems as its not a POSIX file reference; but a microsoft/DOS one)

I think you're looking for https://superuser.com/questions/1606213/how-do-i-get-back-unused-disk-space-from-ubuntu-on-wsl2

@muru omg it works for me!!!! Thank you!!!!!!!!!!!!
